# Maintain the Responsiveness of the Site

Tags: html, css

Before, we had a page looking like [this](http://sb.kidsdial.com/colored-marble-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html)

[image]

After we made some modifications we now have a page looking like [this](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/colored-marble-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html)

[image]

For removing the empty spaces in the page, we did some coding as below.

We are using this code, but responsiveness of the site is gone after using the code below.

Please guide me as to what code changes are needed to maintain responsiveness.

```
.block.block-list.block-check-delivery{ 
   position : relative; 
   bottom:85px !important;
}
.p{ 
   float:none  !important;
}
.usually{
   position:relative; 
   bottom:90px !important;
}
.dinfo{
   position:relative;
   bottom:90px;
   right:50px !important;
}
.catalog-product-view .add-to-cart-wrapper{ 
   height: 60px;
   width:45%;
   float:right !important;
}
.sampleclass{
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../images/product_view_line.png") no-repeat scroll;
   display: block !important; 
}    
.text-move{
    position:relative; 
    bottom:21px; 
    font-weight:bold;
}

.font-move{
    font-weight:bold;
    position:relative;
    bottom:2px;
}
.color-name{
    font-weight:bold;
    position:relative;
    top:2px;
}

.text5{     
    position:relative;
    left:10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what was the code look alike before the changes?

Comment: @LajosArpad as there is lot of codes, please check with view page source, before it was looking like [this](http://sb.kidsdial.com/colored-marble-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html) , later we added code present in question, after that only it spoiled.

Comment: @LajosArpad now i removed all code posted in question and made it as like before, now i want to remove empty spaces present in [link1](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/colored-marble-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html) & i want to make it like [link2](http://sb.kidsdial.com/colored-marble-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html) , please help me for this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following style in your css and try

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    #aitcg_image_container13,
    #raphBot_13,
    #printable-area-image,
    #raphTop_13
    { 
        max-width:100% !important;
    }

    #aitcg_image_container13{ 
        margin-left:0 !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its working in the link http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/colored-marble-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html

Comment: please check here : http://prnt.sc/c6dukm once we check the site with minimizing window bar, its looking ugly & not responsive.

Comment: Press ctrl+f5 on that page and check or clear the cache and check

Comment: i tried as you said, also tried in private window , but if we minimize the screen, still its displaying like this : http://prnt.sc/c6dukm

Comment: I modified the style, change and check once again

Comment: sorry, still its not looking good if we minimize browser screen.

Comment: now i removed all code posted in question and made it as like before, now i want to remove empty spaces present in [link1](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/colored-marble-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html) & i want to make it like [link2](http://sb.kidsdial.com/colored-marble-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html) , please help me for this....